# If $Q$ is a prime ideal of $R[x]$ then $QF[x]\cap R[x]=Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I'm filling the gaps in a proof and I'm stuck in this part:

> Suppose $R$ is a UFD and $Q$ is a prime ideal of $R[x]$, if $F$ is the
>   quotient field of $R$ and $R\cap Q=\{0\}$, then $QF[x]\cap R[x]=Q$.

I've been dealing with this problem for some days and every idea I have never works. I consider now is the time to come here, so I hope that some of you could give me a hand with this.

I don't post what I've done in order to solve the problem because, as I have told, anything of it worked.

Hints will suffice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems you missed the following: if $P$ is a prime ideal of a commutative ring $R$, $S\subset R$ a multiplicative set, and $P\cap S=\emptyset$, then $S^{-1}P\cap R=P$. This is very easy to prove and I suggest you to try it. (Btw, this has nothing to do with $R$ being an UFD.)

Comment: Ok, i'm really thankful. I've proved what you suggested me, now I want to apply it to my original problem, I think this is what I need to do:

Your $R$ is my $R[x]$, your $P$ is my $Q$ and $S$ is my original $R$ minus $\{0\}$, I'd only need to show that $QF[x]=S^{-1}Q$ and that's all.

Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is wrong!

Take $R=\mathbb Z$ and $Q=2\mathbb Z[X]$. Then $Q\mathbb Q[X]=\mathbb Q[X]$.

However, if you add to the hypothesis $Q\cap R=(0)$, then the equality holds since then the extension of $Q$ to the ring of fractions $F[X]=S^{-1}R[X]$, where $S=R-\{0\}$, is $S^{-1}Q\ne F[X]$.

Comment: This answer was posted before the edit (which was actually suggested in the answer) of the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified that. I was about to thank you, but the other answer appeared and I began to analyze it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Devilathor Actually there are no *two* answers: in my comment under your question I wanted to clarify you what exactly I've meant in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't even realized it was you the one in the comment under my question. Thanks again, you took me out from a jam. I only have one last question if you don't mind: $S^{-1}Q$ is defined as $\{q/s:q\in Q, s\in S\}$ and $QF[x]$ is the set of all finite sums of elements of the form $qf(x)$ with $q\in Q$ and $f(x)\in F[x]$, isn't it? Can I define $S^{-1}Q$ as the set of all finite sums of elements of the form $q/s$ with $q\in Q$ and $s\in S$?

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes, but why define the last ideal in that way? If you add all that fractions you get only one with numerator in $Q$ and denominator in $S$.

Comment: You're right, I just wanted to be consistent with the definition I know of the product $IJ$ as the set of all finite sums of elements of the form $ij$. I think i can see $QF[x]$ as the intersections of all the ideals of $F[x]$ that contains $Q$, am I right? I'm asking that because I want to see the best way to prove that $S^{-1}Q=QF[x]$, but I guess is not difficult.

Comment: I think it's easier to think of $F[X]$ as being $S^{-1}R[X]$ as I've already pointed out in my answer. This way you will have a similar description of the elements of $QF[X]$ to the ones in $S^{-1}Q$.

Comment: Can I argue this?: $QF[x]=Q(S^{-1}R[x])=(QR[x])S^{-1}=QS^{-1}$, If i can, I'd like to justify the "asociative law" in that product.

Comment: Even better: the elements in $QS^{-1}R[X]$ are sums of products of the form $q(f/s)$ with $q\in Q$, $f\in R[X]$ and $s\in S$. Summing all these you get an element of the form $q'/t$ with $q'\in Q$ and $t\in S$.

Comment: But $Q$ is an ideal of $R[x]$, wouldn't that imply that $QR[x]=Q$ (and so $S^{-1}QR[x]=S^{-1}Q$)?

Comment: My comment was edited. See it again. (But what you said can be used as a step in your argument before my previous comment.)

Comment: Ok, so that's true then. I think that's all, I've solved my problem. I say it again: I'm really thankful, you have been very kind with me.

Comment: Of course, almost forgot it. Keep on doing a great job please.